# Add "e.g." in parenthesis of parencite

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I use Biblatex for reference managing. I would like to add an "e.g." to the parentheses before "(Freedman, 2008)" in

```
 \parencite{freedman_comparison_2008}
```

I tried

```
 \parencite[e.g.]{freedman_comparison_2008}
```

but it results in "(Freedman, 2008, e.g.)". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`biblatex` citation commands  support two optional arguments: a prenote and postnote.  If you only supply one, it is interpreted as the postnote. So to use a prenote alone, you need to explicitly provide the brackets for the postnote:

```
\command[⟨prenote⟩][⟨postnote⟩]{⟨keys⟩}
```

where `\command` here is any citation command.

So in your particular example you need to use:

```
\parencite[e.g.][]{key}
```